# Updating database with node.js and angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have an app which posts, gets and deletes data and I would like to add 'update' functionality as well but I can't figure it out..
I have a node.js server which has such api:

```
app.get('/api/feedbacks', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get all feedbacks in the database
    getfeedbacks(res);
});

// create feedback and send back all feedback after creation
app.post('/api/feedbacks', function(req, res) {
    // create a feedback, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    FeedBack.create(req.body, function(err, feedback) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the feedbacks after you create another
        getfeedbacks(res);
    });

});

// delete a feedback
app.delete('/api/feedbacks/:feedback_id', function(req, res) {
    FeedBack.remove({
        _id : req.params.feedback_id
    }, function(err, feedback) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        getfeedbacks(res);
    });
});
```

and such angular service which speaks to node api:

```
service.factory('FeedBacks', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {
        create : function(feedBackData) {
            return $http.post('/api/feedbacks', feedBackData);
        },
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/feedbacks');
        },
        delete : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/feedbacks/' + id);
        } 
    }
}]);
```

That way I can post, get and delete data.

My goal is to add also update function.

What I have tried on node:

```
// update a feedback
app.put('/api/feedbacks/:feedback_id', function(req, res) {
    // edit a feedback, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    FeedBack.put(req.body, function(err, feedback) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the feedbacks after you edit one
        getfeedbacks(res);
    });
});
```

on Angular service:

```
update: function(editFeedId, editedFeed){
            return $http.put('/api/feedbacks/' + editFeedId, editedFeed);
}
```

controller looks like:

```
$scope.editFeed = function(id) {
    $scope.editFeedId = id;
    $scope.editedFeed = 'replace this txt'


    FeedBacks.update($scope.editFeedId, $scope.editedFeed)
        // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new
 feedBacks
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log('updated');
             $scope.feedbacks = data; 
        });
};
```

I get 500 error as I execute editFeed(). I couldn't figure out to configure that! Where do I do wrong? Any Tips?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're using express on the Node.js server, right? If yes, are you using express **body-parser**? If you're not using it, your req.body will return null and it will not save the data. That's why the status 500.

Comment: @AndreyLuiz yes, I use express and I use body-parser..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Mongo here, in which case your update statement is incorrect.

It should be something like:

```
app.put('/api/feedbacks/:feedback_id', function(req, res) {
      FeedBack.update({_id: req.params.feedback_id}, req.body, function(err, feedback) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the feedbacks after you edit one
        getfeedbacks(res);
    });
});
```